# Hexadecimal to decimal in Java

Tags: java, hex, decimal

**Where is my mistake ?**

> The results are often 48 to high. For the 0 case i will add an If-statement. I want the stay with both loops if it is possible :)

```
public static int HexadecimalToDecimal(String hex1) {

        char hex[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

        int intCache = 0;
        int runner = 0;
        int help = 0;
        int number = 0;

        for (int i = hex1.length(); i > 0; i--) {


            while (hex1.charAt(i - 1) != hex[help]) {
                help++;
                number = hex[help];
            }
            intCache += number * (Math.pow(16, runner));
            runner++;
        }

        return intCache;

    }
```

Comment: Side note: method names start with lower case, and their names should be around "verbs", like "retrieveValueFromHexString" for example. Besides; I assume this some sort of assignment; so doing it like that is ok; but for "real world" usage .... you can use various built-in functions that take strings and turn them into whatever number.

Comment: i know these code conventions, but i don´t use them for my private programs because i´m (the only one) reading them. It´s like waiting for the

Comment: Still: follow the conventions. Assuming that you are sharing code with people at some time ... why would you want to practice something that you should not be using then? Programming style is very much about "being used" to something. Why allow yourself getting used to "bad practices"?

Comment: Get good habits. When you post your code here you are not the only one reading it anymore....

Comment: okey ,okey i will stay on good habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run

```
            number = hex[help];
```

number is assigned the character value (`'0'`), not the numeric value 0.  The character value for '0' is 48.